# zip command seems to not doing its job correctly

Tags: zip

I use a USB drive to save/load some docker images to/from a USB flash disk and distribute it amongst the team.

This is my script to `save` one of the images:

```
echo "Saving some/image ..."
docker save some/image > /Temp/Docker/SomeImage

echo "Zipping some/image ..."
zip SomeImage.zip SomeImage 1>/dev/null

echo "Copying some/image to USB ..."
cp /Temp/Docker/SomeImage.zip /media/$USER/Docker
sync

echo "some/image done."
```

Nothing fancy or complicated. Save the image, zip it, and copy it to USB. That's it.

Then I use this script to `load` it:

```
echo "Copying some/image from USB ..."
cp /media/$USER/Docker/SomeImage.zip /Temp/Docker
sync

echo "Unzipping some/image ..."
unzip SomeImage.zip 1>/dev/null

echo "Loading some/image ..."
docker load < /Temp/Docker/SomeImage

echo "some/image done."
```

Again, nothing complicated. Copy from USB, unzip it and load it.

However, sometimes it's x MB in the USB, sometimes y MB. And when it's x MB, it can not be unzipped, complaining that it's corrupt.

Why is it so? Why is the zip command not acting deterministically here?

P.S. Or maybe something happens here that I'm not aware of. Maybe the combination of these commands is causing the problem here.

**Update**

This is the error I get:

> ```
> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.
> ```
>
> note:  SomeImage.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
> unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of SomeImage.zip or
> SomeImage.zip.zip, and cannot find SomeImage.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: `sometimes it's x MB in the USB, and sometimes it's y MB` can you give examples of x and y

Comment: First thing to do would be to not discard zip's output and see if there's anything different there.

Comment: @JaromandaX, for example, 600MB and 619MB.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better and easier to use gzip with pipes:

```
docker save some/image | gzip >/media/$USER/Docker/SomeImage.gz

gunzip < /media/$USER/Docker/SomeImage.gz | docker load
```